# Retrieve data in mysql with foreign key relationships over multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, database

I have read everything I could find on the web regarding JOIN and foreign key relationships, but can not seem to get my head around a solution to solve my problem.

As you can see in the relationship diagram image my **CUSTOMER** table have a foreign key relation with **TASK_IN** table. 
**TASK_IN** table have a foreign key relation with **TASK_ID** table.

I want to retrieve all data from the **TASK_ID** table. Can this be done via the **CUSTOMER** and **TASK_IN** table foreign key relation - if yes, how would the SQL query look (PHP)?

[image: Relationship diagram]

Comment: ... Sorry my bad. The tag is now removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM task_id AS taskid INNER JOIN task_in AS taskin ON taskid.id = taskin.id INNER JOIN customer AS cust ON taskin.id = cust.id WHERE id = YOUR_VALUE_HERE
```

EDIT:

this is just basic sql syntax, you can read more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp).

Comment: Please explain your answer